# Facebook is not redirecting to https when accessing tab URL

Tags: php, facebook

im having a facebook app which is hosted in https only.
this is one of installed sample https://www.facebook.com/nintriva?sk=app_236578386381406
But what my problem is that when im accessing the url from http it is not  showing anyhtng.
Actually i need to the users to redirect to https when they are accing my app from their tab of fan pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using PHP with Apache, so you can easily do this by changing the settings of the server in the files `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Alternatively you can do this by sending a redirection header through PHP. This has to be done **before** any actual output is sent.

```
<?php
// Ensure the request goes through HTTPS
if (!$_SERVER['HTTPS']) {
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
  header('Location: https://your-app');
  exit;
}
// Do the other stuff
```

Comment: But you know in my facebook app settings there is only https URL given and there is no http URL so that reason how can i get user attention to redirect them to https when they are accessing through http?

Comment: i need to convert the entire facebook fan page to https when user accessing my app from their fan page tab

Comment: i think i may need to rehost my app in http also and give that URL in app settings.So that i can redirect from that code to my https app.i think its the only solution for this

Comment: Do you think this is there is any other solution for this?

Comment: Could you provide me some additional information on your facebook app? Is it hostet on an Apache web server or not? Do you have normal PHP files whereever you host it? Look at my answer again.

Comment: Ok. 1. Did you try the PHP code I posted above? 2. What about adding the instructions above to your `.htaccess` file?